# How to check for a TypeVar actual type and keep mypy happy

Tags: python, mypy

I have a type bound defined as

```py
T = TypeVar("T", bool, int, str)
```

and I want to pass **type** (not a value) T to a method, defined as

```py
def env(value_type: Type[T]) -> Optional[T]:
```

and in the method, based on the type of T, return values with matching type. This works (see example attached), but mypy says that

```
test_generic.py:20: error: Incompatible return value type (got "bool", expected "str | None")  [return-value]
test_generic.py:22: error: Incompatible return value type (got "int", expected "bool | None")  [return-value]
test_generic.py:22: error: Incompatible return value type (got "int", expected "str | None")  [return-value]
test_generic.py:24: error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "bool | None")  [return-value]
test_generic.py:24: error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "int | None")  [return-value]
```

What's the reason? How can I fix it?

test_generic.py:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Type, Optional

T = TypeVar("T", bool, int, str)


def get_str() -> str:
    return "str"


def get_int() -> int:
    return 1


def get_bool() -> bool:
    return True


def env(value_type: Type[T]) -> Optional[T]:
    if value_type is bool:
        return get_bool()
    elif value_type is int:
        return get_int()
    elif value_type is str:
        return get_str()
    else:
        return None


def test_int() -> None:
    assert env(int) == get_int()


def test_bool() -> None:
    assert env(bool) == get_bool()


def test_str() -> None:
    assert env(str) == get_str()
```

Versions used:

```bash
$ python --version
Python 3.11.1
$ mypy --version
mypy 1.5.1 (compiled: yes)
```

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to use `ts = Union[str, int, bool]; def env(value_type: Type[ts]) -> Optional[ts]:` and get rid of typevar.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but may I suggest using the built-in [functools.singledispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) decorator? It invokes the correct handler method based on the first argument's type, avoiding the possibly lengthy `if type...` checks.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! Using a `Union` works fine, also `singledispatch` seems very powerful.

Comment: This seems like a failure of mypy type inference. Another option is https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload This is arguably better than `Union` as it preserves the property that the input type determines the output type, although for this particular code `singledispatch` looks good as it separates the implementations too (singledispatch is more of a runtime focused feature than purely for type-checking).